# "NameError: global name 'change' is not defined" + other errors

Tags: python, batch-file

I am fairly new to Python, and I am currently using Python 3.3.3 just in case you were wondering. Below is my code, which I translated from whatever language Batch Script is written with, to Python. [Here](http://pastebin.com/S7JefiYu) is the Batch Script code. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but when I run this, I get `NameError: global name 'change' is not defined`. I used http://pych.atomidata.com/code to check the syntax, and if you input my Python code into the box to check it, all you get is a couple code errors, and some Pep-8 errors. I can't think of what else is wrong. I don't even know what most of the code errors are, and the Pep-8 errors are all `Line: __ Column: __ E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1`.

```
import subprocess as sp

global change
global count

def numberInput():
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input("Input a number, please: "))
            sp.call('cls', shell=True)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a valid input...')
            sp.call('pause', shell=True)
            numberInput()

    change = number
    numberVerify()

def numberVerify():
    if change == 0:
        numberCorrectIsTrue()
    else:
        number = change

def numberCorrectIsTrue():
    count = count + 1
    integer = number

    # checks to see if the input
    # is valid or not.
    if number != integer:
        sp.call('cls', shell=True)
        print("Please enter a valid number!")
        loop()
    else:
        even = number % 2

    if even == 0:
        print("Substituting x in 'x / 2' with {}".format(number))
        answer = number / 2
    else:
        print("Substitiuting x in '(3 * x) + 1' with {}".format(number))
        answer = number * 3
        answer = answerOdd + 1

    print(answer)

    if answer == 1:
        returnStats()
    else:
       numberCorrectIsTrue()

def returnStats():
    print("Your original input of {} returned as 1.".format(change))
    print("A total of {} operations were executed.".format(count))
    change = change + 1
    count = 0
    sp.call('pause', shell=True)
    numberVerify()

def check():
    number = answer
    numberCorrectIsTrue()

numberInput()
```

Comment: there are so many errors in your code I would seriously consider starting from the beginning again.

Comment: I was just thinking that... This is very frustrating...

Comment: If I were you I would spend some time  writing  the pseudocode first, then start coding. It will be  a lot easier to follow code and know what to expect where.

Comment: pseudocode? I apologize in advance. I don't really know that much about python. Also, I translated the file in 5 minutes, so I probably rushed.

Comment: have a look here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Answer (score 2):

These lines:

```
global change
global count
```

should just be

```
change = 0
count = 0
```

The `global` keyword is used when you want to refer to a global variable, so a function using these values should be as such:

```
def func():
    global count
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: thats what I had originally, but that was throwing errors also. I was just getting `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @JamesLynch It was assuming that `count` was a local variable, not yet assigned. It's enough to communicate that `count` is actually global, see updated answer :)

Comment: ok, I changed my code to fit your answer, so that fixed the `UnboundLocalError`, but I am now getting `Line: __ Column: __ local variable '____' is assigned to but never used` and `Line: __ Column: __ local variable '____' (defined in enclosing scope on line 4) referenced before assignment`

Comment: what you have answered does not even cover 25 percent of what is wrong in the code

Answer (score 1):

`global` in a code block isn't inherited by functions inside that code block. Every function that needs to assign to a global variable needs to have its own `global` declaration for that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Add "global change" at the beginning of each function that assigns a value to change or count.

So for instance, numberInput() should look like

```
def numberInput():
    global change
    while True:
    ...
```

Source: [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: OK, that's improved my code, so now I get no errors when running the code through the shell, but now, whenever I enter my input for `int(input("Input a number, please:"))`, it just acts like nothing happened, and shows `>>>` on the next line

Comment: Well at least no syntax error! Unfortunately I won't be able to help any further without knowing about your new problem. I suggest you try troubleshooting a little, then make a new post more specific.

Comment: I noticed in your code though that as long as your input is a number other than 0, your program terminates at numberVerify(), without encountering any print statements. That's probably why you don't see any output in the shell.